# Check whether a DIV contains Image or not

Tags: jquery

I am trying to determine whether a DIV has a image or not. Structure of my DIV is as:

```
<li class="customData">
  <div class="customdata1"><img src="" /></div>
  <div class="customdata1"><input type="text" /></div>
</li>
```

Answer (score 18):

Try this:

```
$('.customData div').each(function() {
    if ($(this).find('img').length) {
        // there is an image in this div, do something...
    }
});
```

This will find an `img` at any level under the `div`. If you only want it as a direct descendant, use this for the `if` condition:

```
$(this).children('img').length
```

Comment: `$(this).find('> img').length` could also be written as `$(this).children('img').length`.

Answer (score 11):

You can use the `has()` selector

```
$('.customData div:has(img)').doSomething()
```

Not sure what you want to do, if you wanted to count them for example:

```
  alert(  $('.customData div:has(img)').length)
```

API Refrence http://api.jquery.com/has-selector/

Answer (score 1):

First things first lets designate the div

`var dD = getElementById("desiredDivID");`

now lets find child elements of the div:

```
var elements = dD.childNodes.length;
```

Now we loop  through every  element node:

```
for(index = 0; index < elements; index++){
node = dD.childNodes[index];
if (node && node.nodeType == 1 && node.nodeName == 'IMG'){
    dD.removeChild(node);
            }
}
```

in the last if statement we check for the node to exist and than check for a node type  and node name. each of theese checks must return true and then .removeChild(node) removes the designated element node, which is marked in 'IMG' string.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this will help

```
if ($(".customData:contains('img')")) {
 console.log("sucess");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, you want to check if it has an image or not, so another way to do this I would say you need to check the src attribute, what happens if you have a img tag but no src? Which happens sometimes in dynamic environments (with actual programming code rather than plain HTML).

```
$('.customData .customdata1').find('img').attr('src');
```

Answer (score 0):

**HTML**

```
<img src="some-url" class="banner-image">
```

Javascript way

```
console.log(document.querySelector('.banner-image').tagName);
```

jQuery way:

```
console.log(jQuery('.banner-image')[0].tagName);
```

> Adding [0] - JQuery element converts to Javascript Dom object. If you are having loop then [0] is not required.

I've just found this while working and it is compatible with any
browser.